# change wireless networks using cmd or batchfile?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-7-x64, wireless

I need to create a batch file for my windows 7 to change from 1 wireless network (BigPondD1CBA1) to my (Home) Network. I have tried things such as google and all I have been able to find with relevant info .

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToConnectToAWirelessWIFINetworkFromTheCommandLineInWindows7.aspx

`netsh wlan connect ssid=Home name=Home interface="WIRELESS NETWORK CONNECTION"`

I have tried

`netsh wlan /?`

But it seems as though I'm coding it correctly but must be missing a step ?
or I'm doing it wrong can someone please help or even just two batch files one to disconnect from my current wlan and one to connect to the other would be fine if some fine genius could help that would be great i think it shouldn't be a hard task but its out of my league thanks in-advance .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was over thinking it the solution to change `accesspoint` is

```
netsh wlan connect name="accesspoint name"
```